# Outlook meeting invites displaying in code in email client

Tags: outlook

My client is sending meeting invites via outlook with an email address registered with 123 reg.
But the recipients  of the meeting invites are seeing the invites being rendered as code like so:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:GMT Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011028T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:-0000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010325T010000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="name, name";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:name@name.co.uk
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20190708T161833Z
DESCRIPTION: \n\n
DTEND;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20190709T210000
DTSTAMP:20190708T161833Z
DTSTART;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20190709T203000
LAST-MODIFIED:20190708T161833Z
ORGANIZER;CN=name@name.co.uk:mailto:name@name.co.uk
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-gb:test meeting invite
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000070637F2BB135D501000000000000000
        010000000586E894D89A913478319BE9F0D0DC9F7
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-mic
        rosoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/
        12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Co
        ntent-Type content="text/html\; charset=us-ascii"><meta name=Generator con
        tent="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--\n/* Font Definition
        s */\n@font-face\n      {font-family:"Cambria Math"\;\n panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 
        3 2 4\;}\n@font-face\n  {font-family:Calibri\;\n        panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 
        2 4\;}\n/* Style Definitions */\np.MsoNormal\, li.MsoNormal\, div.MsoNorma
        l\n     {margin:0cm\;\n margin-bottom:.0001pt\;\n       font-size:11.0pt\;\n    font-fa
        mily:"Calibri"\,sans-serif\;\n  mso-fareast-language:EN-US\;}\na:link\, spa
        n.MsoHyperlink\n        {mso-style-priority:99\;\n      color:#0563C1\;\n       text-decorat
        ion:underline\;}\na:visited\, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\n       {mso-style-prior
        ity:99\;\n      color:#954F72\;\n       text-decoration:underline\;}\np.msonormal0\, 
        li.msonormal0\, div.msonormal0\n        {mso-style-name:msonormal\;\n   mso-margin-
        top-alt:auto\;\n        margin-right:0cm\;\n    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto\;\n  margi
        n-left:0cm\;\n  font-size:11.0pt\;\n    font-family:"Calibri"\,sans-serif\;}\n
        span.EmailStyle18\n     {mso-style-type:personal-compose\;\n    font-family:"Cali
        bri"\,sans-serif\;\n    color:windowtext\;}\n.MsoChpDefault\n   {mso-style-type
        :export-only\;\n        font-size:10.0pt\;}\n@page ....
```

Anyone know how to stop this? Could it be do do with the recipients firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that means you are not setting the MIME message content-type correctly. You really need to include the relevant pieces of your code and show the complete MIME message with all the headers.

Comment: Hi, I am not generating any code, this is all self generated through outlook and its the email client thats not rendering the invite correctly. I have read that it could be spam filters doing it, but wanted to explore all possibilities,